# Purpose of ReadOnly

Tags: c#, readonly

What's the purpose of [the Readonly attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.readonlyattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on properties? Metadata for use elsewhere?

Comment: It is metadata. E.g. PropertyGrid component is using that attribute to gray-out items that programmers want to appear as read-only.

Comment: @alexm what do you mean by "mostly"? It is only metadata.

Comment: The document you reference is fairly clear on it's purpose.  It enforces read-only in a designer environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used in a few places; `PropertyGrid` for example will respect this attribute, allowing it to be read-write in code, but read-only in the UI (strictly speaking, it is the `PropertyDescriptor` that does this - `PropertyGrid` obeys the descriptor; the same effect can be achieved by using custom descriptors). Some serializers may also respect it. It isn't used much, to be honest. If you think that one is obscure - `[ImmutableObjectAttribute]` is used even less; as far as I know, the IDE uses it to decide whether to show attribute properties, when editing attributes. That's about it.